# DropDownList optionLabel not working with multiple attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I using `jquery mobile` for `multiselect` with `ASP.Net MVC 4`, but the `optionLabel` attribute doesn't work with `multiple` attribute.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("nameDropDow", new MultiSelectList(AllPossibleValues, SelectedValues), "Please, select values",
                            new Dictionary<string, Object>  { 
                            {"multiple", "multiple"}
                            }) %>
```

Is there any workaround for this problem ?